# Downloading archives from a virtual machine takes too much time to start

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtual-machine

I wrote a program in Python which downloads a .tar.gz archive from a virtual machine. The download works fine, but the problem is that it takes too much time to start. Here's the part of my code that handles the downloading:

```
import os
from wsgiref.util import request_uri
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

def download(self,dirr):
     file_url = os.environ['location'] + dirr
     headers = [('Content-Description', 'File Transfer'),
               ('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream'),
               ('Content-Disposition', 'attachement; filename="'+os.path.basename(file_url)+'"'),
               ('Expires', '0'),
               ('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate'),
               ('Pragma', 'public'),
               ('Content-Length', str(os.stat(file_url).st_size))]
        
      file_download = open(file_url, 'rb')
      return headers, file_download.read()

def server_app(environ, start_response):
    crt_handler = handler(request_uri(environ))
    headers, response_body = crt_handler.get() // this calls my download function, which is part of a class. 
    status = '200 OK'
    start_response(status, headers)
    return [response_body] 

def start_server():
   httpd = make_server("", PORT, server_app)
   httpd.serve_forever()
```

Sorry if some things don't make sense in my code, I've pasted only the part that does the downloading. The program does much more. Anyway, is it possible to make the downloads start faster?

Comment: The speed of a download is rarely limited by the client but mostly by the server and connection.

Comment: My problem is not the speed of the download, but the time it takes to start. That also depends on the server and connection? @KlausD.

Comment: It does. But in your case it is **your** server. You are fetching the whole file from the remote server and when that is done you are sending it to your client. That explains the waiting time. Your will have to implement streaming HTTP to solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_download.read()` looks wrong. Most of the HTTP libraries support streaming from a file object.

If `make_server` is `wsgiref.simple_server.make_server`, the following might work but I can not test it. The idea is to not call `read` directly the file but use `wsgiref.util.FileWrapper` to convert it to a iterator of blocks. And then return that iterator from the app function.

```
def download(self,dirr):
     file_url = os.environ['location'] + dirr
     headers = [('Content-Description', 'File Transfer'),
               ('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream'),
               ('Content-Disposition', 'attachement; filename="'+os.path.basename(file_url)+'"'),
               ('Expires', '0'),
               ('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate'),
               ('Pragma', 'public'),
               ('Content-Length', str(os.stat(file_url).st_size))]

      file_download = open(file_url, 'rb')
      return headers, wsgiref.util.FileWrapper(file_download) # ***

def server_app(environ, start_response):
    crt_handler = handler(request_uri(environ))
    headers, response_body = crt_handler.get() // this calls my download function, which is part of a class. 
    status = '200 OK'
    start_response(status, headers)
    return response_body # ***

def start_server():
   httpd = make_server("", PORT, server_app)
   httpd.serve_forever()
```

Note above there are two changes. Marked by `# ***`

Comment: Yes, `make_server` is `wsgiref.simple_server.make_server`, I will edit my post.

Comment: I am getting errors when I try to return `wsgiref.util.FileWrapper(file_download)`. One error in `wsgiref\handlers.py", line 204, in write` saying `AssertionError: write() argument must be string` and one in `wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 33, in close` saying that `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`.

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to return `response_body` instead of `[response_body]`. It works and the downloads start way faster. Thank you!